# Order, sorting search in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on oracle stored procedure for search, order, pagination.

For frontend I am using Angular 8 DataTable, for calling stored procedure Python Flask API is used.

Search, Pagination is working fine. Sorting is not working as expected. It works only for one column.

I'm getting an error of order by clause

> inconsistent datatypes expected number got char' for 'USER_CAT' column.

The stored procedure works for 'CAT_ID'

Table is as follows:

```
"CAT_ID" NUMBER(11,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CAT_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ROLE_MAPPING" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROLE_FILTER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GROUPTYPE" NUMBER, 
    "ALLOWMULTIPLE" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("CAT_ID")
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Si_Ibill_CAT_DATATABLE (
    i_order_by   VARCHAR2,
    i_start  NUMBER,
    i_pagesize   NUMBER,
    i_search     VARCHAR2,
    i_draw       NUMBER,
    i_sort      VARCHAR2,
    i_result  OUT NOCOPY SYS_REFCURSOR,
    i_recordcount out VARCHAR2,
    i_recordsTotal out VARCHAR2,
    i_redraw out VARCHAR2
)
AS
vCount Number;
vreCount Number;
BEGIN
 select count(*) into vCount from bill_cats_master;
 select count(*) into vreCount from bill_cats_master
                WHERE (CAT_ID LIKE '%'|| i_search ||'%' OR USER_CAT LIKE '%'|| i_search ||'%' OR CAT_DESCRI LIKE '%'|| i_search ||'%'); 
 i_recordcount := vreCount;
 i_recordsTotal := vCount;
 i_redraw := i_draw;
             OPEN i_result FOR
                        SELECT CAT_ID ,USER_CAT ,CAT_DESCRI ,ROLE_MAPPING ,ROLE_FILTER ,CREATED_DATE,GROUPTYPE ,ALLOWMULTIPLE
                        FROM
                             bill_cats_master
                        WHERE 
                        (CAT_ID LIKE '%'|| i_search ||'%' OR USER_CAT LIKE '%'|| i_search ||'%' OR CAT_DESCRI LIKE '%'|| i_search ||'%') ORDER BY
                        CASE 
                            when i_order_by = 'CAT_ID' THEN CAT_ID
                            when i_order_by = 'USER_CAT' THEN USER_CAT
                        END,
                        CASE when i_sort = 'DESC' THEN 
                            CASE
                                when i_order_by = 'CAT_ID' THEN CAT_ID
                                when i_order_by = 'USER_CAT' THEN USER_CAT
                            END    
                        END DESC
                        OFFSET i_start ROWS FETCH NEXT i_pagesize ROWS ONLY;          
                        dbms_output.put_line( 'i_order_by: ' || i_order_by );
                        dbms_output.put_line( 'i_order_by: ' || i_sort );
END Si_Ibill_CAT_DATATABLE;
```

Sorting should work for all the columns

Comment: The first two counts can be combined to avoid an unnecessary scan of bill_cats_master. `select count(*), count case when ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `CASE..WHEN` expects same data type in its resultant column.

In your example, `CASE..WHEN` in `ORDER BY` clause has columns `CAT_ID`(number) and `USER_CAT`(varchar2) having different data type. Hence, It is throwing the error.

You should revise your query accordingly like following:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN I_SORT = 'DESC' AND I_ORDER_BY = 'CAT_ID' THEN CAT_ID END DESC,
CASE WHEN I_SORT = 'DESC' AND I_ORDER_BY = 'USER_CAT' THEN USER_CAT END DESC,
CASE WHEN I_SORT != 'DESC' AND I_ORDER_BY = 'CAT_ID' THEN CAT_ID END,
CASE WHEN I_SORT != 'DESC' AND I_ORDER_BY = 'USER_CAT' THEN USER_CAT END
```

Cheers!!

Comment: It Worked :) 

Thanks  William Robertson & Tejash